# Is there a way to restrict the application master to launch on particular nodes?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, hortonworks-data-platform, ambari

I have a cluster setup with nodes that are not reliable and can go down (They are aws spot instances). I am trying to make sure that my application master only launches on the reliable nodes (aws on demand instances) of the cluster. Is there a workaround for the same? My cluster is being managed by hortonworks ambari.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by using node labels. I was able to use the property in spark spark.yarn.am.nodeLabelExpression to restrict my application master to a set of nodes while running spark on yarn. Add the node labels to whichever nodes you want to use for application masters.

Comment: I would suggest that yo use non exclusive node labels to do this. You might end up blocking a lot of resources on a particular node if the node label is exclusive